# scope of @m and application helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm a little confused about the purpose of doing this:

```
module SessionsHelper
   def current_user=(user)
       @current_user = user
   end
end
```

source: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code:current_user_equals

because through our controller we set @user, which has a the scope between controller, and views, so why do we need to define it explicitly?

Also, the explanation is allows for:

```
redirect_to current_user
```

how does the function current_user, know when I say redirect_to (function) im talking about @variable_path ? (in this case user_path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more than 90% rails developers know that( and its now been the part of Rails Convention Over Configuration we can say)

- current_user represents User object
- current_user represents just not any user, but one who logged in

When you look at rails code, and you find @user, you need to read through a couple of lines where @user is defined, to know why it is defined, whats the purpose of it. Thats not the case with current_user, as it represents the logged in user.

About your 2nd question,

```
  redirect_to some_object # or any function that returns some object
```

when you pass any object to redirect_to, redirection happens for the url

```
  "/#{object.class.name.tableize}/#{object.id}"
```

which suppose to be a page, a 'show' page, detailing out object to end user

object_path or object_url make the same url

Comment: I would suggest, avoid using object_path or object_url such url helpers to simply generate url string, reason being, they are very expensive, eat a lot of time. IMO simply urls also looks much more readable otherwise.

Comment: so using current_user is only for readability and has noting to do with scope and/or control flow issues? Also, what's the alternative to object_path?

Comment: yes its nothing to do with scope, control etc. its just that ror developers started using it long time back and now everyone follows it. Alternative to object_path, I will say it is "/objects/#{object.id}". Still most of the ror developers would encourage you to stick to object_path, unfortunately I am not able to point out any related discussion happened here w.r.t. it. But I have seen experts still emphasize on using object_path, as it is more readable as per most of us here.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is smart enough to know that `current_user` has an `User` object behind it.

That said, Rails can redirect to the proper location.